# Ошибки в работе приложения после годового обновления Windows 10

Tags: vb.net

Возможно, после годового обновления Windows 10 требуется указывать полный путь для `System.Globalization` для web сайта

> Ошибка: путь\файл(строка): error BC30561: "Globalization",
>   импортированный из пространств имен или типов "System.Web, System",
>   является неоднозначным.

У кого есть информация по данной проблеме

Answer (score 1):

Столкнулся точно с такой же проблемой. Добавление `System` решило все. Хотя `System` рисуется тултипом как избыточный.

Comment: Пожалуйста, пишите более развернутый ответ.